# magnitude of the best approximants denominator for an irrational number

Tags: diophantine-approximation

If the irrationality measure of an irrational number $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is some $\mu>0$, it implies that for $\mu'<\mu$ there are infinitely many couples of integers
$(p_n,q_n),n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$|x-p_n/q_n|<q_n^{-\mu'}.$$

The $p_n,q_n$ can be expressed by the means of the continued fraction of $x$.

Is it possible ***in general*** to choose the $q_n$ with a not too large magnitude, such as $q_n\leq C n^a$ for some $C,a>0$?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "choose" $q_n$. $q_n$ is uniquely determined by $x$ and $n$, unless you don't mean $p_n/q_n$ as the $n$-th convergent of $x$?

Comment: I'm not a specialist, but from any infinite sequence you can extract a strict infinite subsequence, so there is a choice. I don't know if there is a "maximal subsequence", or if the n-th convergent always satisfies the inequality, but that might indeed help answer the question.

Comment: The $p_n, q_n$'s satisfy a recurrence of the form $p_n = a_n q_{n-1} + p_{n-2}$ and $q_n = a_n p_{n-1} + q_{n-2}$, where $a_n$ is the $n$-th partial quotient. Since $a_n \geq 1$ for all $n$, each of the sequences $\{p_n\}, \{q_n\}$ grows at least exponentially fast (at least as fast as the Fibonacci numbers), so the inequality you wrote down can only be satisfied for finitely many $n$ for fixed $C,a$.